# Initializing char * class member with string literal

Tags: c++

I came across this code in an online test. Is this code safe ? What is the lifespan of the literals I am using to create the instances  ? Does the literal "John" gets destroyed after p1 is instantiated (as that completes the expression in which the literal is used).

```
class Person {
    public:

    char *name;
    Person(char *s) { name = s}
    inline void setName(char *newName) {name = newName;}

};

int main(){

    Person p1("John");

    Person p2("Steve");

    p1.setName("Rick"); 
    p2 = p1;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

the char * isn't being deleted anywhere (or free'd) so it is safe.  An exception will be thrown if you attempt to free it, as the literals are stored in a different part of memory to the dynamic memory.  Literals live for the lifetime of the process.

Comment: Define "safe". If you document that the class may only be constructed from a string literal then fine, but it has major ownership/lifetime problems otherwise. It's a really poor design. As for "the .bss section of the executable", well that's a matter for the implementation, not defined by C++, and the implementation has not been specified in the question.

Comment: _"An exception will be thrown if you attempt to free it"_ That is also an implementation detail also likely down to pure chance. Code to standards and you'll have a much better time. That's literally why they are there.

Answer (score 2):

The code is illegal, because a string literal cannot initialise a `char*`. So, no.

It becomes legal if you make the type `const char*`. But then, it is still not safe.

*If* you can guarantee that only a string literal will be passed in, then that's fine, because a string literal is guaranteed to live for the duration of the program. Your class will not make the literal get destroyed.

But you can't guarantee that. You can only document it as a precondition, and that's really weak.

This is a really poor design.

Comment: inb4 the whining, no, it's 2015 now

Comment: Actually, it was legal in C++03, but deprecated.

Comment: OK, I think I can decrypt that comment now. Still, four years is sadly not enough to make all legacy code and examples go away, so it was worthwhile to point out.

Comment: Disagree that it's a poor design (assuming `const char *` is used instead). It's OK to have classes that don't dynamically allocate copies of everything. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I do not suggest that people "dynamically allocate copies of everything". In fact you of all people should be well aware that I advise against it more often than not. But the code in question _is_ of a poor design. It's incredibly error prone and does not belong in any modern program.

Comment: It's a great class for holding people whose names are string literals.

Comment: @ex-bart: You had a lot more than four years. The entire purpose of deprecation is to give you good notice to get your act together and make the code changes before you have to. At time of writing, you've had 17 years. That is, since the day C++ was standardised. Is that really not enough time? It's longer than many members of this community have even been _alive_, for goodness's sake. Plus, it's not like one day in 2011 someone suddenly announced that the conversion was now illegal; we knew it'd happen several years before that. I have no sympathy for lazies wilfully ignoring deprecation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit realistically, I'd expect people to start fixing those pieces of their around the time compilers start making -std=c++11 the standard.  At least they can't complain they there was no heads-up.

Comment: @ex-bart: Either way, it's currently illegal and I'm deliberately not going to make accommodations for people using antiquated/broken code — they can do that out of the scope of this modern answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this code safe?

Direct answer: No. It's poor design for several reasons, but in particular that class is taking raw pointers and holding onto them.

> What is the lifespan of the literals I am using to create the instances?

They're stored statically in any implementation, so basically until the end of `main`.

> Does the literal "John" gets destroyed after p1 is instantiated

Nope it's still there, but nothing refers to it anymore (no pointers or references) so you can't get back at it without some shenanigans.

Comment: " It's poor design for several reasons, " - can you go into that in more detail

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit didn't realize that you wrote this answer